# FireFox recognised text/event-stream as a download

Tags: firefox, event-stream

Is there a way to view the content-type:text/event-stream in FireFox instead of download?
e.g. https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange

I am able to view the url directly in Chrome browser. However, FireFox will try to download it instead of displaying the response in browser.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to view the data in the browser?

Comment: I want to see the result quickly without waiting for the huge file to download.

Comment: Use `curl https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange`. A browser is the wrong tool for that.